# Envelope of isoperimetric ellipses

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find envelope of ellipses $ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y}{b^2}=1 $ which have $a,b$ and its associated eccentricity $e$ variable while holding its perimeter

$$ p= 4 a E(e) $$

as constant.

Expected to be asteroid-like, passing through

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{\pi a}{2} \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\pi a}{2} \\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  p &= 4a E(k) \\
  a(k) &= \frac{p}{4E(k)} \\
  F(x,y,k) &=
  x^2+\frac{y^2}{1-k^2}-\frac{p^2}{16E^2(k)} \\
  \frac{\partial F}{\partial k} &=
  \frac{2ky^2}{(1-k^2)^2}-
  \frac{p^2}{8E^3(k)} \left[ \frac{K(k)-E(k)}{k} \right]
\end{align*}

The envelope is given by $$F=\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial k}=0$$

On solving,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{p}{4kE(k)}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \pm \sqrt{1-\dfrac{(1-k^2)K(k)}{E(k)}} \; \\[5pt]
  \pm (1-k^2)\sqrt{\dfrac{K(k)}{E(k)}-1} \;
\end{pmatrix} \, , \quad 0<k<1 \tag{1}
$$

If we adimit $a<b$, then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{p}{4kE(k)}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \pm (1-k^2)\sqrt{\dfrac{K(k)}{E(k)}-1} \; \\[5pt]
  \pm \sqrt{1-\dfrac{(1-k^2)K(k)}{E(k)}} \;
\end{pmatrix} \, , \quad 0<k<1 \tag{2}
$$

> A plot of the envelope for $p=4$ with the ellipses is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Why does the envelope still depend on parameter $k$?

Comment: Usually, we eliminate the parameter to get an implicit equation.  However in this case, it's unlikely to get an implicit equation in close form.  Why not we parametrize with it?  A bit jump outside the box this time.

Comment: Can we see a sketch of  the Asteriod? can we get its natural/intrinsic  equation?

Comment: The plot of the envelope is posted.  It looks like a cushion.

Comment: In the first option $y$ calculates to zero, but not to the expected value $\pi a/2 $ ; Also you plotted $1.$

Comment: You set $p=4\times \dfrac{\pi a}{2}=2\pi a$, if take $p=4$, then $a=\dfrac{2}{\pi}$ .i.e. $\dfrac{\pi a}{2}=1$.

Comment: In the meantime could the cushion be parameterized only in terms of $p,$ thus eliminating/avoiding $ k$, which should be absent in the singular solution/envelope?

Comment: Fitting special points, we may get an approximate relation
$$\Large |x|^{\frac{\ln 2}{\ln \pi-\ln \sqrt{2}}}+|y|^{\frac{\ln 2}{\ln \pi-\ln \sqrt{2}}} \approx \frac{p}{4}$$ which holds good.