# One-parameter family of conics

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

This question might seem vague, but what does a one parameter family of conics mean? Is it similar to how we define a one-parameter family of curves?

Comment: It is indeed an instance of a one-parameter family of curves, as a conic is a curve.

Answer (score 1):

Different parameters serve different purposes.  We can observe how the mathematical nature evolves by varying one particular parameter.  See below, several examples with the varying parameters in $\color{red}{red}$:

- Conics with fixed semi-latus rectum and focus:

  $$r=\frac{\ell}{1+\color{red}{e}\cos \theta}$$
- Conics with fixed [periapsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis) and focus:

  $$r=\frac{r_p(1+\color{red}{e})}{1+\color{red}{e}\cos \theta}$$
- Family of conics touching the axes at $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$:

  $$
  \left(
    \frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}-1
  \right)^2
  =\frac{2\color{red}{\lambda} xy}{ab} \tag{$\lambda \ne 0$}$$
- Confocal central conics:

  $$\frac{x^2}{a^2+\color{red}{s}}+\frac{y^2}{b^2+\color{red}{s}}=1$$
- Confocal parabolae:

  $$y^2=2\color{red}{\lambda} x+\color{red}{\lambda}^2$$
- Lissajous figures of two signals with the same frequencies:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{2xy\cos \color{red}{\phi}}{ab}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}
=\sin^2 \color{red}{\phi}$$

- Isoperimetric ellipses (see more on the link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177371/envelope-of-isoperimetric-ellipses/2177960#2177960)):

  $$x^2+\frac{y^2}{1-\color{red}{k}^2}=
   \left[ \frac{p}{4E(\color{red}{k})} \right]^2$$

  $$\frac{x^2}{1-\color{red}{k}^2}+y^2=
   \left[ \frac{p}{4E(\color{red}{k})} \right]^2$$

  [image]

Comment: A "real-life" example: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabole_de_sûreté